# how to display embed and link in razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i'm trying to find out how to display youtube enbed and youtube link in razor
i'm using this @html.raw(item.MyUrl) and it is diplaying the "embed " data but i'm trying to find out (if can do ) a way to display also the youtube link (look like this(http://youtu.be/9hUy9ePyo6Q)
i have tryed decode and encode they also work  in enbed but not by the Url link
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.MyUrl))
*@@*         @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.MyUrl))
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use the item.MyUrl directly instead of using html.raw() ??

Comment: Nop, i need to display the movie itself

Comment: try using iframe to display the videos. For youtube videos the code is as follows
<iframe src="http://youtube.com/embed/[your video ID]"></iframe>
it will display the movie